# How to dynamically make channels in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have this scenario in which there is a full mesh between all nodes in Hyperldger Fabric. There is one channel between each two nodes. When a new node joins this business network, by a new node please consider it as a new company joining this consortium, it is therefore necessary to make a channel between this new node and each of the existing nodes. The more nodes joining this network, the more manual work is necessary. I would like to know if there is a way or any tools to enable dynamically creating channels between nodes. So ideally whenever a new node joins the business network, automatically new channels are created between this node and each of the other nodes. (I am looking for something like a trigger to create channels.)

Please consider that I am using Hyperledger Composer to develop my proof of concept. So if there is a capability in composer to do so that is especially helpful.

I appreciate any help or guidance.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: no, not yet. I wonder if there is a solution for it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an API (Spring Boot Microservice) which can be used to create the channel of given name into the hyperledger fabric blockchain network dynamically.

Here is complete [code](https://github.com/SirajChaudhary/api-create-newchannel-into-blockchain-network) on my github page

https://github.com/SirajChaudhary/api-create-newchannel-into-blockchain-network

Please read the wiki as well out there for HowTo steps.